# Execute a command stored into a $variable

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I made a script where I wrote:

```
COMMAND="/usr/bin/exiftool $PATH_NAME"
.... code ....
$COMMAND
```

The variable $PATH_NAME is assigned dynamically inside a while loop.
The command works fine until it encounters files with spaces (for example PATH_NAME="Add Driver.png"). 
The console output is:

```
File not found: ./Add
File not found: driver.png
```

The command should be:

```
/usr/bin/exiftool ./Add driver.png
```

I think the problem is given by the spaces in the $PATH_NAME. I tried also to execute directly the command:

```
eval "/usr/bin/exiftool $PATH_NAME"
```

But same output error. Any idea to solve the problem? thanks.

Comment: Yes, tried but same error.

Comment: This problem is [BashFAQ50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using simple strings, build your command using arrays. Arrays provide a convenient interface: If `a` is an array, then `"${a[@]}"` (note the quotes) expands into each element of `a`, *without* additional field splitting or globbing (so spaces, and things like wildcards, should remain intact).

Example:

```
$ a=(printf "|%s|\n" "foo   bar" "*")
$ echo ${a[@]}
printf |%s|\n foo bar bin boot dev etc home lib lib64 lost+found mnt opt proc root run sbin srv sys tmp usr var
```

Note how the `*` was expanded, and how the extra spaces between `foo` and `bar` were lost. But with the `"${a[@]}"`, these are preserved:

```
$ echo "${a[@]}"
printf |%s|\n foo   bar *
```

This is ideal for building commands. Now, you can do:

```
$ "${a[@]}"
|foo   bar|
|*|
```

See? The arguments were retained perfectly.

So, do:

```
COMMAND=(/usr/bin/exiftool "$PATH_NAME")
"${COMMAND[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

glenn jackman's point is well taken. But, to solve your immediate use case, how about backticks? Like so:

```
`echo $COMMAND`
```

For example, this works:

```
COMMAND='ls /'
`echo $COMMAND`
```

Comment: -1 Why `\`echo $COMMAND\`` and not just `$COMMAND`? They have the same effect (except for some corner cases of which the `echo` variant has more).

Answer (score 1):

For more detailed explanations about how Bash interprets spaces, I recommend to read this: [Bash variables and command substitution](http://www.compciv.org/topics/bash/variables-and-substitution/)

**Clean solution**

Expanding a variable can lead to unexpected and sometimes catastrophic results if the variable contains special characters:

```
user@host:~$ do_something $some_variable
```

Expanding a variable within double-quotes can prevent such problems:

```
user@host:~$ do_something "$some_variable"
```

**Explanation**

The case encountered here is described at the end of the post:

> **The dangers of unquoted variables**
>
> In an ideal world, everyone would keep their string values short and without space/newline, or any other special characters.
>
> [...]
>
> But when people start adding special characters to filenames, such as spaces, expanding variables, without the use of double quotes, can be dangerous.
>
> [...]
>
> So the main takeaway here is: **double-quote your variable references whenever possible**.